# ComputerCraft get Item Id inside Blood Magic altar

Tags: computercraft

I'm trying to automate a Blood Magic Altar in Enigmatica 2 Expert Skyblock (1.12.2). I'm trying to get the ID of the item inside the altar but this does not work. I searched a lot and have not found any solution which worked.
So here is my option, which does not work:

```
local altar = peripheral.find('bloodmagic:altar')
print(altar.getAllStacks()[1].all().id)
```

The error, which occures, is that getAllStacks on the altar returns nil, although there is something inside the altar.

Any one any soltuion regarding this? Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the item's name by doing this:

```
local altar = peripheral.find('bloodmagic:altar')
print(altar.list()[1].name)
```

If you want to differentiate between the different slates you can use their damage value (the number after the "/"):

```
print(altar.list()[1].damage)
```